# Google Go: binding multicast socket

Tags: network-programming, go

Google Go doesn't allow to bind UDP socket to multicast address. It just sets address to zero if it is multicast (see [src/pkg/net/sock_posix.go, `listenDatagram` function](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/sock_posix.go#L161)).

The question is: can I somehow bypass this limitation?  If not, is there some 3rd party socket library or piece of C code that could help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a listening multicast UDP socket with [`net.ListenMulticastUDP`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenMulticastUDP).  It will take care of creating the socket for you and binding it to the desired network interface and multicast group address.

To get an interface to pass as the second argument,, you probably want to use either [`net.InterfaceByName`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#InterfaceByName) or [`net.Interfaces`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces).

Comment: it doesn't take care of bind() so if i try to create two sockets that should connect to X.Y.Z.A:1234 and another one to connect to X.Y.Z.B:1234 (note the last octet) i get 2 sockets that get *both* streams. i need to bind(2) the socket to make kernel filter only groups that are explicitly requested.

Comment: Shouldn't each socket only be receiving traffic to the multicast groups it has joined?